# ntlm authentication using OSB in Jdeveloper 12.2.1

Tags: rest, jdeveloper, ntlm, osb

Is there a way to add NTLM authentication using OSB(to invoke a rest service) in JDeveloper 12c(12.2.1)?

Comment: Have you visited these links - 
1. https://community.oracle.com/thread/926227
2. http://rcttechblog.blogspot.in/2011/06/ntlm-authentication-with-osb.html
3. https://beatechnologies.wordpress.com/tag/ntlm-authentication-in-osb/

Comment: Thank You, It was helpful.. :)